# Exception has occurred: ValueError too many values to unpack (expected 2)line 13

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, openai-gym

im getting an error saying:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
too many values to unpack (expected 2)
  File "D:\Game Developlment\AI\Learning\Pong ai NEAT\mainTutorial.py", line 13, in <module>
    model.learn(total_timesteps=20000)
```

im trying to follow a [(this tutorial)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mut_u40Sqz4) which is about Reinforcement learning in python. im 59:17 in to the video(if that matters) and i really want to be able to train my own AI. Does anyone know a fix? I dont get any errors in the terminal, but it doesnt do anything

Code:

```
import os
import gym
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from stable_baselines3.common.evaluation import evaluate_policy

Environment_name = 'CartPole-v0'
log_path = os.path.join('Training', 'Logs')# Make your directories first
env = gym.make(Environment_name)
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])
model = PPO('MlpPolicy', env, verbose=1, tensorboard_log=log_path)

model.learn(total_timesteps=20000)
```

I was trying to get this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBRUM.png) in the terminal
but i didnt get anything in the terminal

im 13 years old

im using vs code

Comment: Please post the full traceback, not just the first line.

Comment: You say both "im getting an error saying ..." and "I dont get any errors in the terminal".  I don't see how both of those can be true.

Answer (score -1):

```
    # To avoid ValueError when unpakcing too many values apart from observations
class CustomDummyVecEnv(DummyVecEnv):
    def reset(self):
        for env_idx in range(self.num_envs):
            obs, *_ = self.envs[env_idx].reset()
            self._save_obs(env_idx, obs)
        return self._obs_from_buf()

    def step_wait(self):

        for env_idx in range(self.num_envs):
            obs, rew, done, info = self.envs[env_idx].step(self.actions[env_idx])
            self.buf_rews[env_idx] = rew
            self.buf_dones[env_idx] = done
            self.buf_infos[env_idx] = info
            if done:
                obs, *_ = self.envs[env_idx].reset()
            self._save_obs(env_idx, obs)
        return (self._obs_from_buf(), self.buf_rews, self.buf_dones, self.buf_infos)


env = gym.make(environment_name)
env = CustomDummyVecEnv([lambda: env])
obs = env.reset()
model = PPO('MlpPolicy', env, verbose=1)

total_timesteps=20000
model.learn(total_timesteps)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).